# WP: Page Not Found

Tags: wordpress

I am using WP-3.3.2 and had created a website [eyepractice](http://www.eyepractice.ca/optometris/guelph/?month=5&year=2012) my script gets month and year from url and then shows calendar for that month and year but when I integrate with Wp it only work for year 2012 and if I use http://www.eyepractice.ca/optometris/guelph/?month=1&year=2013 it shows Page Not Found however I have already created a Page named guelph from Wp admin. I searched whole project for 2012 but it is not hard coded.

[image]

Comment: is the page found without the `$_GET` params?

Comment: I passes month=1&year=2013 my script catch $_GET['month'] and $_GET['year']

Comment: I meant this: http://www.eyepractice.ca/optometris/guelph/ now the page is found. I'd advise to change the param names, apparently these params give errors. If that doesn't help check you script for errors.

Answer (score 1):

This is a REALLY old question, but I came across it while looking for solution to the exact same problem, so I will leave an answer here.
I used a calendar creation script based on this link:
http://davidwalsh.name/php-event-calendar

In Wordpress apparently using 'year' and 'month' as $_GET variables conflicts with Wordpress internal query variable handling, so the calendar only worked for current year for me and threw a 'page not found' error on the next year.

The solution was simple. As @janw suggested, change the parameter names. In the script wherever $_GET variable is called 'month' or 'year', change it to something else like 'cal_month' or 'cal_year'. Works like a charm.